# How to get same OpenID URL at Launchpad and StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, login, launchpad

My usual nicks of don-quixote, quixote and donquixote were already in use at Launchpad when I registered there, so I registered as mdcrawford, my real name.

At all the StackExchange sites - which includes this one, AskUbuntu - I registered under the nick I prefer, Don Quixote.

This resulted in two different OpenID URLs being created.  I would tell you what they are but I can't figure out now how to get The Series of Tubes to tell me what they are.  But one of them ends in "mdcrawford", the other ends in I think "donquixote".

Isn't OpenID meant to be a single sign-on service?  Shouldn't I have just one OpenID URL?

I have a whole bunch of Ubuntu bugs to report, but it took me a couple weeks to figure out how to sign into my existing LaunchPad account, as I had registered with an email address that I no longer use much anymore.

Comment: I actually had three OpenID URLs.  I got rid of one of them (I hope) by merging mdcrawford and quixote-dulcineatech at LaunchPad.